# searchbar in swift using parse

Tags: swift, parse-platform, uisearchbar

Hello I have been watching a video to do this code yet nothing is working I tried to play around the code and still didn't get what's wrong. the problem is that I don't have any mistake and when I run the code it's not showing results in the tableView. what I want to do is I want to search in parse user list.
here's the code:

```
func searchBarSearchButtonClicked(searchBar: UISearchBar){
    searchBar.resignFirstResponder()
    print("search word =\(searchBar.text)")

    let usernameQuery = PFQuery(className: "User")
    usernameQuery.whereKey("username", containsString: searchBar.text)

    usernameQuery.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock {
        (results: [PFObject]?, error: NSError?) -> Void in

        if error != nil {
            let myAlert = UIAlertController(title:"Alert", message:error?.localizedDescription, preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)

            let okAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default, handler: nil)

            myAlert.addAction(okAction)

            self.presentViewController(myAlert, animated: true, completion: nil)

            return
        }
        if let objects = results! as? [PFObject]{
            self.searchResults.removeAll(keepCapacity: false)

            for object in objects{
                let usernameid = object.objectForKey("username") as! String
                self.searchResults.append(usernameid)
            }
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()){
                self.myTable.reloadData()
                self.mySearchBar.resignFirstResponder()
            }
        }
    }
```

}

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell{
    let myCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("myCell", forIndexPath: indexPath)

    myCell.textLabel?.text = searchResults[indexPath.row]

    return myCell
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath){
    mySearchBar.resignFirstResponder()
}

func searchBarCancelButtonClicked(searchBar: UISearchBar){
    mySearchBar.resignFirstResponder()
    mySearchBar.text = ""
}


func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

    return searchResults.count
}
```

}

Comment: What isnt working exactly? Did you try to debug it?

Comment: when I use the searchbar it doesn't show a results in the tableveiew

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## TL;DR

You are not unwrapping the search string from `UISearchBar`.

## Details

When looking at [Apple's official documentation for `UISearchBar`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UISearchBar_Class/), then it can be seen that the `text` property is of the type `String?`.

When looking through your code with this knowledge, then the following line looks a bit suspecious since you are not performing unwrapping of any kind:

```
usernameQuery.whereKey("username", containsString: searchBar.text)
```

This can be studied even further with a simple Playground test:

```
import UIKit

let searchBar = UISearchBar()
searchBar.text = "Kumuluzz"
let output = searchBar.text
print("Output: \(output)")
```

The output (seen in the right sidebar) in this playground is the following:

```
"Output: Optional("Kumuluzz")\n"
```

This means that my username would have to be `Optional("Kumuluzz")` in order to match your query in the `User` base.

So in conclusion, apply some sort of unwrapping on the `text` property.

Comment: If my answer to your question was helpful and was fulfilling, then please accept it as the answer to your post to indicate towards other users that your issue has been resolved :) http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work